# The shortest way to return an array with less elements

Tags: php

I have two arrays.  I wish to return the array containing fewer elements.

My code so far:

```
<?php

if ( count($a) < count($b) )
    return $a;
else
    return $b;
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `return (count($a) < count($b)) ? $a : $b;`, there isn't any shorter way of doing it afaik

Comment: yes, thats the nice answer, I will accept your solution !

Comment: *Minus point* makes sense here, since your code has syntax errors, just like your english. Either way, looks like billyonecan and Laurens gave you the correct answers.

Comment: You better give comment so I will update my question. Your way of doing neither to doing any good to anybody or the forum. You will get what you give !

Comment: The nature of this action is really bad, it is not encouraging people to ask question

Comment: Laurens has jsut copied the answer given by billyonecan I guess, so no upvote to that answer

Comment: @Ms.Nehal: Since Billyonecan not submit answer, I only give him credit, and I will accept Laurens answer. You can't say he copied Billy... if you don't know it exactly, he may just submit it the same time with the comment.

Comment: What behaviour do you want if the arrays contain the same amount of elements?

Comment: Had no intention of copying billyonecan' answer. Was writing my answer at same time he commented. I will remove my answer if billyonecan will submit an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way of doing it is fine. You could use the ternary `?` operator to create a shorter if statement though:

```
return (count($a)<count($b)) ? $a : $b;
```

Comment: Thanks for submitting the answer !

Comment: How you are creating these arrays?

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 that has nothing to do with his question so that is irrelevant

Comment: here we used count two times i think OP also have count of array elements that's why i asked so that we can use that count directly inseted of again calling `count()`;